# Max date in SQL Server consultation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I need to get the row with the maximum date by the `ItemKey`.

I need the whole row.

I have this table:

```
num | ItemKey | Serial | Qty | ItemName | Tdate
----+---------+--------+-----+----------+-------------------------
1   | 111     | 5      | 10  | AAA      | 2010-03-25 00:00:00.000 
2   | 111     | 0      | 12  | AAA      | 2010-03-26 00:00:00.000 
3   | 222     | 6      | 13  | BBB      | 2010-03-25 00:00:00.000 
4   | 222     | 2      | 11  | BBB      | 2010-03-28 00:00:00.000 
5   | 333     | 3      | 15  | CCC      | 2010-03-25 00:00:00.000 
6   | 333     | 4      | 16  | CCC      | 2010-03-26 00:00:00.000 
7   | 333     | 0      | 17  | CCC      | 2010-03-27 00:00:00.000
```

I need to get this:

```
num | ItemKey | Serial | Qty | ItemName | Tdate
----+---------+--------+-----+----------+--------------------------
2   | 111     | 0      | 12  | AAA      | 2010-03-26 00:00:00.000 
4   | 222     | 2      | 11  | BBB      | 2010-03-28 00:00:00.000
7   | 333     | 0      | 17  | CCC      | 2010-03-27 00:00:00.000
```

I tried this SQL statement:

```
select * 
from MyTBL 
where Tdate = (select MAX(Tdate) from MyTBL)
```

But unfortunately it does not work

Thanks

Comment: What if there are multiple records with the MAX(Date)?  Should it return a data set or are there further selection requirements needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve this

```
SELECT * FROM (
select *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemKey  ORDER BY Tdate DESC) as rn from MyTBL) AS T1
WHERE rn = 1
```

or in another way *(using common table expressions)*

```
WITH CTE_1 AS (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemKey  ORDER BY Tdate DESC) as rn from MyTBL)
SELECT * FROM CTE_1 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Why `ItemName` instead of `ItemKey`

Comment: @Sami it was a mistake :)

Comment: Sure it was Hadi ;)

Comment: Might be worth noting that if there are `ItemKey`s that have more than one record with the same `MAX(Tdate)`, this will just choose one record at 'random'

Answer (score 0):

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e4b3/6)

You can use this :

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
join (select ItemKey, max(Tdate) Tdate from table_name group by ItemKey) as t2 
      on t1.ItemKey=t2.ItemKey and t1.Tdate=t2.Tdate
order by t1.ItemKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this;

```
   select * from MyTBL M1 inner join
    (select ItemName,max(Tdate) as Tdate from MyTBL group by ItemName) M2
    ON M1.ItemName = M2.ItemName and  M1.Tdate = M2.Tdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH t AS ( SELECT *, 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemName ORDER BY TDate DESC ) as myRank FROM MyTBL)
SELECT [num], [ItemKey], [Serial], [Qty], [ItemName], [TDate] FROM t 
WHERE t.myRank = 1
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/675a6/16)